# SQL - in operator behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL code that basically looks like this:
(I know that it doesn't make much sense but bear with me)

```
  select * 
    from Table1 
group by Table1.col1 
  having count(*) in (select col1 
                        from Table2)
```

When I try to run it, it doesn't return anything, but if I replace the **in** operator with **=** then all works fine.

I don't understand this behavior, if someone could help me understand I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Imagine it something like this: ````HAVING 5 in (5)````. A count can only be a number, so why are you not trying to match it 1 = 1?

Comment: I am just guessing, Are you sure IN clause does not have any null value in (select col1 from Table2)

Comment: @Alex - If I have something like this: HAVING 5 in (5,2,4) - this would return true. So my question is why does't HAVING 5 IN (5) doesn't return true as well.

Comment: @ItalianStallion: Sure you can. `Where IntCol in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)` is perfectly valid and functional. The code in this question doesn't make any sense, but IN works fine with int values.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b1b7/1 - Can you check this please?